# Tomcat: List of Command Line Parameter/Arguments

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I've moved a Production application from Tomcat 5.5.23 to 6.0.29, and my question is - are my command line arguments/parameters still valid?

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m 
                  -Xmx2048m 
                  -XX:MaxPermSize=192m 
                  -XX:NewSize=251m 
                  -XX:MaxNewSize=251m 
                  -XX:PermSize=32m 
                  -XX:SurvivorRatio=5 
                  -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 
                  -XX:+UseParNewGC 
                  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 
                  -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

I'm gathering they are because the application is up and running, but I haven't had any luck turning up a definitive list - the windows server documentation is the top link when I google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the options for your JVM. to get the definitive list for the version you are running you can type `java -h` for the standard options and `java -X` for the non-standard options "the -X[X] options

Comment: +1: That explains why I couldn't find anything when I was googling.